# Как с вайбера отправить на сайт сообщение и обработать на PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, viber

Скажите как с вайбера отправить на определенный номер фото и текст к фото
Кака Использовать API вайбера чтобы фото сохранить на диске сайта, а текстовое сообщение перед фотографией определить как зарезервированное слово к примеру "товар # 255" Сайт будет знать что в базу нужно записать фотку под айдишником 255

Answer (score 1):

Итак, в [разделе "начало работы"](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#getting-started) официальной документации не очень очевидно, но всё-таки описывается создание апи ключа, получение сообщений как типа коллбэков "message", а также регистрация коллбэков.

### Получение апи ключа (["начало работы"](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#getting-started))

тыкаем "редактировать инфо" (edit info) нашего **паблик аккаунта** (не обычного! обычного нельзя) и там можно получить API-ключ

### Создаем скрипт получения событий ([Receive message from user](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#receive-message-from-user))

Например по адресу `https://example.com/my-viber-script.php`. **https с валидным сертификатом обязателен**.

Скрипт создаем с кодом вроде такого

```
<?php
$x = json_decode($y=file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
if($x['event']=='message' && $x['message']['type']=='picture'){
    // $x['message']['media'] - это ссылка на картику!
    file_put_contents('msg'.$x['message']['message_token'].'.txt',$y);
}
echo 'Этот текст нужен, чтобы веб-сервер не вернул 206 вместо 200';
```

### Установка хука (раздел [Webhooks](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#webhooks))

отправляем POST-запрос с данными:

```
{  
   "url": "https://example.com/my-viber-script.php",  
   "event_types": ["delivered", "seen", "failed", "subscribed", "unsubscribed", "conversation_started"]  
}
```

по адресу `https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/set_webhook`

`https://example.com/my-viber-script.php` обязательно надо заменить на адрес своего скрипта. **https с валидным сертификатом обязателен**.

не смотря на то что в типах событий (`event_types`) нет `message`, они всё равно придут, т.к. message, subscribed и unsubscribed обязательные типы.

после этого он отправит запрос на наш скрипт, который должен вернуть 200 Ok, и ответит "ура, вебхук установлен!"

Теперь отправляем картинку и смотрим как она прилетает в наш скрипт.

Текстовое сообщение будет в переменной `$x['message']['text']` - его можно распарсить, например, регэкспами, например, для сообщений вида "Tovar #123"

```
if(preg_match('tovar ?# ?(\\d+) ?/i',$x['message']['text'],$m)){
    // $m[1] == 123
} else {
    // формат не подошел
}
```

По-хорошему надо бы ответить пользователю результатом, это описано тут - https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#send-message